# Geonames autocomplete city/state, return full state name not abbr

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I am attempting to use this jQuery example to pull back a city and state name combo. I was wondering is there any way to pull back the actual state name and not the abbreviation? For instance: it currently returns Boise, ID and I want Boise, Idaho ... http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You just have to pass a `template` parameter to the Web service to tell it how you want your response formatted.

For your situation, your `data` object would look like this:

```
data: {
    q: request.term,
    template: "<geobytes city>, <geobytes region>"
}
```

Check out the documentation [here](http://www.geobytes.com/free-ajax-cities-jsonp-api/) for more information.